# More efficient way to copy data from one workbook (dynamic name) to active workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my current method of selecting a workbook with a dynamic name (generated each time I generate the report):

```
Sub SelectWorkbooks()

Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> "PERSONAL.XLSB" And wb.Name <> "Tracker.xlsb" Then
       wb.Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Tracker.xlsb").Sheets("OfficeAppointments").Cells
       wb.Close
       GoTo EndAll
    End If
Next wb

EndAll:
End Sub
```

This... works. But it's probably slow and inefficient as it loops through as many as three workbooks to determine if it should take the information from it and paste it to the Tracker.xlsb file.

The only constant in the generated file name is `OfficeAppointments_JT_`, if that helps. Is my code the best it can be, or can we improve upon it any?

Comment: Seems efficient enough to me. If you wanted to refer to a workbook with a name containing `OfficeAppointments_JT_`, you'd still have to loop through all workbooks to find that particular one.

Comment: Did you time it?  Even if you had a dozen workbooks open you're not going to notice that loop...

Comment: @TimWilliams I haven't timed it, but that's a good suggestion. If the consensus is that this is the most efficient way, then it may be the other bits of code that I have going through that may seem to be "slow". I simply thought it was this as I had optimized the rest as best I could, too. Maybe I should time each sub separately, then! Thanks!